# Shield Platform Encryption

Tags: platform-encryption, shield-encryption

I was trying to implement Platform encryption in my org. Salesforce does not encrypt a field if it is referenced in where clause of a soql in a class and send you an email stating that field can not be encrypted as it is referenced in a class. However I was able to encrypt a field in spite of the fact that it was referenced in where clause of a soql in a class. And cherry on the cake, even when I have now removed the encryption from field still I can not edit that class because it says a field in where clause is encrypted. Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: this is interesting, did Salesforce Support shed light on this topic?

Comment: Yeah they updated that its some bad data issue. They ran some background job to fix it.